# Does "aurea" have the second meaning?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

Does "aurea" have the second meaning?

According to [Latin Word Study Tool](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=aurea&la=la#lexicon), aurea doesn't mean "the bridle of a horse" in the following context in my opinion:

"trecenta quoque scuta **aurea** trecentorum aureorum, quibus tegebantur singula scuta"

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? It's not clear what meaning you are referring to and how it is "obsolete"?

Comment: Perhaps you can expand your question a bit? Information like that should be in the body of the question, since it's pretty much impossible to understand the question without that context!

Comment: Lewis & Short is not referring to this quotation. The shields are undoubtedly golden and not bridles.  Nevertheless, *aureas* are bridles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case the word isn't [*aurea*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DA%3Aentry%20group%3D91%3Aentry%3Daurea) but [*aureus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daureus), an adjective meaning "golden, of gold"—in the feminine singular and neuter plural it looks just like *aurea* "bridle", but the "golden" meaning is much more common.

Very literal translation:

> *trecenta quoque scuta aurea trecentorum aureorum, quibus tegebantur singula scuta*
>
> And also three hundred golden shields [made] out of three hundred golden [shekels] (with which each individual shield was covered).

The grammar here is kind of awkward, but the point is that Solomon had so much gold he could use ninety thousand shekels of it to make shields.

Comment: To complement this excellent answer: the quotation is from 2 Chron. 9:16: trecenta quoque scuta aurea trecentorum aureorum quibus tegebantur scuta singula posuitque ea rex in armamentario quod erat consitum nemore.

Comment: Surely only 90,000?

Comment: @TomCotton Oops, right, off by an order of magnitude

Comment: Still quite a lot of shields!

Answer (score 3):

The important quotation is

> the bridle of a horse: *aureas dicebant frenos, quibus equorum aures religantur,* Paul. ex Fest. p. 27 Müll.
>   "They call the reins ***aureas,*** with which the ears of horses are bound up."

In the third section of Ainsworth's lexicon, ***Index Vocum*** (Dialects) *'aureas'* is explained as **both** a dialect adjective meaning 'of the ears,'  a head-stall, **and hence** by synecdoche 'the bridle itself.'

He adds

> [ *qu.* orea, frequens enim est commutatio *o* in *au,* ap. ant. quod fit  in *oro equi,* ...]  and then gives an example from Greek.

Finally he mentions Aureax [ *cf* auriger] a carter. But these are all late or dialect forms.